# How does email hosting work if have a email hosting provider and also automated emails

Tags: web-hosting, email

My website domain example.com is going to be routed through CloudFlare then to the Host.

for the Email, for support and contact, I will use a seperate Email Host provider, (for support@example.com and contact@example.com), do I need to route this through cloudflare then to the provider or can the DNS be directly to the email host. Is their any security flaws with having the website through cloudflare and email host without cloudflare direct?

additionally, I plan to have automatic emails sent from a service for verification codes when users sign up, and also automatic emails sent when specific statuses in the database change (eg, status for a payment is Complete, sends a email using a template and the amount that we sent, or if their is an error in their payment), these emails will be sent from eg no-reply@example.com.  How does this work regarding if I use one host provider for email then a automated service, but sending from the same @example.com domains.

Answer (score 1):

1. When configuring **Cloudflare**, it becomes your authoritative DNS provider. Everything DNS related is managed there (and no longer at your server or registrar).
2. It's perfectly fine to use another email provider. You will configure an **MX record** on the Cloudflare DNS console that redirects to your email provider's servers for it to work.
3. In addition to MX, you must configure **SPF, DKIM and DMARC** for email to work properly.
4. If you are going to send email from another server, you have to register it in the proper records mentioned in step 3 as authorized to send emails on behalf of *example.com*

Comment: Thanks, have you any recommendations for a email host provider that will not automatically put my emails in spam box, and that is reliable and secure?

Comment: That's more of a commercial decision, not a technical one. I cannot recommend any provider without violating SE guidelines. However, I do recommend using a subdomain to mitigate the risk of spam flagging. You configure a subdomain to send the emails from, and if it gets flagged by spam, it applies on the subdomain level protecting your main domain.